# How to have two series display differently on the same graph

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have two series on the same chart visualization (with two different elasticsearch queries), I put them on two different axes but I'd also like one to be bars and the other to be lines

I've seen it on graph examples but I can't find the option to do it in the settings, I can only enable/disable lines/bars/points for all series at the same time

I figure this question might have already been asked but if so it seems I can't find the right search terms to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `series override` menu. With it you can match legend test and then customize match by match.

[image]